# Trying to burn 1% off each transcation

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, dapp-development

Can anybody show me how to add a code for burning %1 of each transaction?

https://github.com/strainzeh/MADToken/blob/main/MADToken.sol

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work

```
function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public {
    // Fee 1%
    uint256 fee = amount / 100;
    require(_balances[msg.sender] >= amount);

    // Credit 99% to recipient
    _balances[recipient] += (amount - fees);

    // Remove 100% from sender
    _balances[msg.sender] -= amount;

    // Burn fee
    _totalSupply -= fee;

    // Emit transfer events
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, recipient, amount - fee);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, address(0x0), fee);

    return true;
}
```